# Is there a way to display TableLayout in ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-arrayadapter, android-tablelayout

I have 10+ tables created in xml Tablelayout and i'm trying to
put them in ListView rather than in a ScrollView .
Tables are not editable and just for info... How to put them as 
data source in Adapter or i need to Inflate or what? tnx and sorry for noobish q..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom Adapter for the ListView(please search this). With the adapter you need to create ListView item layout, where you can define your table for each row in the List View.
Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply adding TableLayout to ListView row layout xml.

Example from my current application:

```
public class DistributorsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Context context;
private final int rowResourceId;
private final JSONArray data;

public DistributorsListAdapter(Context context, int rowResourceId, String[] ids,   JSONArray data) {
        super(context, rowResourceId, ids);

        this.context = context;
        this.rowResourceId = rowResourceId;
        this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

    try {
        JSONObject rowData = data.getJSONObject(position);

        // Заполняем данными строку списка
        setHTMLData(rowView, rowData, "name", R.id.distributor_table_title );
        setHTMLData(rowView, rowData, "address", R.id.distributor_address );
        setData(rowView, rowData, "website", R.id.distributor_website );
        setData(rowView, rowData, "phone", R.id.distributor_phone );
        setData(rowView, rowData, "fax", R.id.distributor_fax );
        setData(rowView, rowData, "email", R.id.distributor_email );

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rowView;
}

private void setData(View v, JSONObject data, String key, int textViewId) throws JSONException{
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(textViewId);
    tv.setText(data.getString(key));
}

private void setHTMLData(View v, JSONObject data, String key, int textViewId) throws JSONException{
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(textViewId);
    tv.setText( Html.fromHtml( data.getString(key) ) );
}
```

}

XML layout of a ListView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/distributor_table_vertical_padding">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distributor_table_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/distributor_table_vertical_padding"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_title_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/distributor_address"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distributor_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/distributor_table_columns_margin"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/distributor_website"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distributor_website"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/distributor_table_columns_margin"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/distributor_phone"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distributor_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/distributor_table_columns_margin"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/distributor_fax"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distributor_fax"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/distributor_table_columns_margin"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/distributor_email"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distributor_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/distributor_table_text_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/distributor_table_columns_margin"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```